# How do I upload a build to TestFlight from a beta version of Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8 Beta 4.  When I archive the project and then hit Upload to App Store with the intent to distribute the build through TestFlight, I get an error from Xcode saying:

`Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be build with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds`

I understand that I can't go to the App Store until Xcode 8 GM is released, but is there a way to simply distribute through TestFlight with a not-yet-Gold Master version of Xcode?  The version of the app I'd like to have tested won't build with Xcode 7 because I've migrated to and utilized some new features in Swift 3.0

Comment: Can you export the binary signed for the App Store and manually upload it to iTunes connect?

Comment: When you say "manually upload" what part of iTunes Connect are you referring to? Like through Application Loader? Tried that but I get the same error as through Xcode.

Comment: Maybe I'm misremembering but I thought you could archive and export an IPA for the App Store and manually upload it to iTunes Connect through your browser.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in iTunes Connect.  In fact it explicitly says `Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later.` in the iTunes Connect portal. Both of those systems are giving me failures :/

Comment: Apple never take builds made via beta versions - and unfortunately there is no other way around

Comment: You can do it now with Xcode 11 beta 4